AWS ECS Multiple Commands, don't exit on first error
I'm running multiple commands in the ECS, and I need all of them to run even if one before them fails.
I tried this command:
"command": ["dbt source freshness --project-dir $DBT_PROJECT_DIR --target prod && python3 -m awscli s3 cp my_project/target/sources.json s3://my_bucket/dbt/"]

My issues is, container exits, when the first command has any errors, BUT I need for 2nd (and all following) command to execute even if the first command returns an error.
Is there a way to do this? Thank you!

Replace && with ;.

Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

I've replaced && with ; as suggested by Yuri in the comments, and it works as I wanted to.
